# after conversation with hosting provider, i have been suggested two alternatives which i dont quite understand

Tags: php, mysql, http, key

I've been trying to connect to a mysql db through a php script. All the code is perfect and everything is well. I upload all the content and scripts to my site and it seems that my hosting provider have blocked all access to connecting to remote db's.

After contacting them, they seem to say that they cannot alter the block, under any circumstances but they do offer me some alternatives to get me through what i'm trying to do.

Now I've done some research on the two alternatives suggested but still don't understand how they work and how i would go about using them for what i'm trying to do (simply connect to a mysql db).

Changing hosting providers is out of my option so i cant just switch. Need to find a way round this.

Comment: You need to tell us what you are trying to do at the end. The MySQL connection seems to be your preferred solution but what is the task that you are trying to do?

Comment: Hey. Once the script has connected to the DB, it will look for certain data in the database and by using the "if" function, it will process different pieces of script depending on weather the information from the db was correct (matched the correct value) or not. I'm just having issues actually connecting to the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they are trying to say you need to use http to make query on remote mysql. You can make a call in php to

http://remotesite.com/query_user_list.php

and query_user_list.php can create an xml file you can use that xml on your current hosting account.